# Pytorch Linear Regression wrong result on particular dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, linear-regression

I'm using pytorch to implement a simple linear regression model.
The code works perfectly for randomly created datasets, but when it comes to the dataset I wanted to train, it gives significantly wrong results.

Here is the code:

```
x = torch.linspace(1,100,steps=100)
learn_rate = 0.000001
x_train = x[:100]
x_test = x[100:]
y_train = data[:100]
y_test = data[100:]
# y_train = -0.01*x_train + torch.randn(100)*10 #Code for generating random data.
w = torch.rand(1,requires_grad=True)
b= torch.rand(1,requires_grad=True)

for i in range(1000):
  loss = torch.mean((y_train-(w*x_train+b))**2)
  if(i%100==0):
   print(loss)
  loss.backward()
  w.data.add_(-w.grad.data*learn_rate)
  b.data.add_(-b.grad.data*learn_rate)
  w.grad.data.zero_()
  b.grad.data.zero_()
```

The result it gives makes no sense.
[image]

However, when I used a randomly generated dataset, it works perfectly:

[image]

The dataset actually looks similar. I am not sure for the reason of the inaccuracy of this model.

Code for plotting data:

```
plt.plot(x_train.numpy(),y_train.numpy())
plt.plot(x_train.numpy(),(w*x_train+b).data.numpy())
plt.show()
```

--
Now the problem seems to be that weight converges much faster than bias. At the current learning rate, bias will not converge to the optimal. However, if I increase the learning rate just by a little, the weight will simply diverge. I have to set two learning rates.
However, I'm wondering whether setting different learning rate is the best solution for a simple model like this, because I've found out that not much model actually uses different learning rate for different parameters.

Comment: Can you also show the code you use for plotting the obtained values?

Comment: @learner updated code for generating data and plotting data

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct, but your model converges slower when there is a large bias in your data (because it now has to update the bias parameter many times before it reaches the correct value).

You could try running it for more iterations or increasing the learning rate.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that if I choose a slightly larger learning rate, the weight will just diverge. It seems that weight converges much faster than bias. I have to give weight and bias a different learning rate to solve the issue. But I'm wondering whether giving weight and bias a different learning rate is the optimal solution (because most gradient descent I've seen uses the same learning rate across all the parameters)